# Problema com mostrar dados no ArrayList

Tags: java

Estou com um problema para mostrar os dados no arraylist, ele sempre mostra o resultado duplicado

```
public static void main (String[]args){
   Scanner ler=new Scanner(System.in);
   Pessoa p=new Pessoa();

ArrayList<Pessoa> listaDePessoas= new ArrayList<>();   

    System.out.println("Digite o seu nome: ");
    p.setNome(ler.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Digite sua idade: ");
    p.setIdade(ler.nextInt());
    listaDePessoas.add(p);
    ler.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Digite o seu nome: ");
    p.setNome(ler.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Digite sua idade: ");
    p.setIdade(ler.nextInt());
    listaDePessoas.add(p);

    for(int i=0;i<listaDePessoas.size(); i++){
        System.out.println("Nome: "+listaDePessoas.get(i). getNome());
        System.out.println("Idade: "+listaDePessoas.get(i). getIdade());
    }
```

resultado: 
Nome: Luis
Idade: 19
Nome: Luis
Idade: 19

Answer (score 4):

Cara, parece que por você estar utilizando a mesma variável (p) para inserir, você está inserindo a mesma variável toda hora, aí você modifica-a e modifica automaticamente toda a lista.
Experimente assim que for inserir uma outra pessoa faça assim:

```
p = new Pessoa();
```

e prossiga com o programa, assim você está criando outro objeto, ok?
Abraço.

Comment: Isso mesmo! `p` é uma referência. Portanto, de maneira simplificada, qualquer alteração feita em `p` irá refletir em todos os lugares onde esse tal `p` é referenciado, no caso, todos os itens dentro do `ArrayList`.